# If else command in python: Is it possible to check character by character resulting in one output?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

```
g = raw_input("What gender would you prefer Male or Female? (Please press m or f): ")
p = raw_input("Please enter your 10 digit Phone Number: ")
reasons = raw_input("Please enter your reason by pressing 1-4: ")
r = reasons
valid_mp3 = g+p+r
print valid_mp3
f12312312345
```

output is in the form of:  gender (f) phone# (1231231234) Reason (5)
Is there any way to state:

```
if getFirstCharacter(valid_mp3) == 'f':
    # miscellaneous command
if getSecondCharacter(valid_mp3) == '1'
    # miscellaneous command
```

How to implement `getFirstCharacter` and `getSecondCharacter` for instance?

Comment: Why are you concatenating all the answers together, anyway? There have got to be easier ways...

Comment: I dont think you can use parentheses like that ...

Comment: You can use string indices as per Xaranke's answer, but why wouldn't you just check against the inputs that your valid_mp3 string comes from?  ex.  if g == 'f': do_something()

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't think that was meant to be valid Python, just a way to explain us what he's trying to do.

Comment: ahh I understand ... strange way of showing us ... but now I see

Comment: @JoranBeasley I proposed an edit to make it look more understable and python valid.

Answer (score 2):

Just work against g and p, unless there's some reason you can't.

```
if g == 'f':
    # do something for females
else if g == 'm':
    # do something for males
else:
    # invalid input
```

Same thing with the first character of p:

```
if p[0] == '1':
    # do something for first character of '1'
```

No sense in trying to do anything complex with the concatenated version if you already have the split versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use string indices like this:

```
if valid_mp3[0] == 'f':
    miscellaneous command
if valid_mp3[1] == '1':
    some other command
```